# <meta> inside <blockquote> allowed?

Tags: html, html-email, meta-tags

I looked at the HTML in an email created by Thunderbird:

```
<blockquote cite="mid:56BB0694.4060809@example.com" type="cite">
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  ...
</blockquote>
```

It is new for me that `<meta>` is allowed here.

I guess Thunderbird wants to tell the parser that the content in the blockquote has this charset.

Do the widespread HTML parsers (Chrome, Firefox, IE) support `meta` in `blockquote`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `meta` element is only allowed in a `blockquote` element (or anywhere else in `body`) if the `meta` element has

- an `itemprop` attribute (from Microdata), or
- a `property` attribute (from RDFa).

([Microdata and RDFa extend HTML5](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/55133/17633) so that this is allowed.)

So the `meta` element from your question is not allowed; your example is invalid.

Answer (score 2):

It is [not valid](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-meta-element) outside of `<head>`, if it doesn't have an attribute `item-prop`.

In your case I am quite sure, that it's the residue of some copy 'n pasting from an earlier e-mail. This meta data could, e.g., come from a rich text editor like Word or LibreOffice, when retrieving clipboard content from them as HTML.

As of supporting: Well, browsers are quite lenient. However, they will not scope the encoding to the content of the `<blockquote>`, and will also only respect it, if it is found in the first [512 bytes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta#attr-charset) of an HTML document.